# Star based rating doesn't fill in the whole star

Tags: html, css

I have implemented star rating with decimal values which works. The problem is that as you can see on the attached picture that the yellow does not fill in the whole star under it and the background shows.

```css
.star-ratings {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}
.star-ratings .star-ratings-top {
  color: gold;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0.5;
  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.star-ratings .star-ratings-bottom {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings">
  <div class="star-ratings-top" id="star-ratings-top1"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-bottom"><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></div>
</div>
```

Does anybody see what is the mistake with the styling so that the stars get filled in completely?

Thank you very much in advance!

[The stars screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Odl0.png)

Comment: Other styles probably influence this, because when i tested your code, it worked well.

Comment: it runs fine for me as well, check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cyLb6gr/). Also try cleaning your `cache` in the browser.

Comment: Same here, the only thing "wrong" I see is the z-index: 0.5. This should be an integer value not decimal.